# Android Layout Difference Between Different API Levels

Tags: android, android-layout

My question revolves around the general problem represented by a specific example.

When I create a button with the following markup:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLookup"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/go_button"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

And deploy the app to an API Level 10 device, the height of the button is considerably less than the height of the same button when deployed to an API Level 17 device - that is, the smaller button does not fill the height of the other items in it's horizontally aligned liner layout whereas the larger version does.

This may have to do with fill_parent vs match_parent, I'm not sure.

The problem I'm having with this is how to define a layout that makes fundamental properties like this the same across devices.

If the answer is, you don't - you use multiple layout files then my next question is what resources do people use to iron this stuff out?  For example, is there a list somewhere of the differences between api levels so that someone could consult it, our do others just suss these things out through trial and error?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in rendering of a layout from one device to another should not be related to the version of Android running on the device. The difference, however, can be(and mostly is) due to different screen densities and dimensions.

This problem is (to some extent) nullified by using `dp`(density pixel) instead of `px`(pixel) while dimensioning views. You can further reduce the oddities by using different `dimens.xml` for different screen densities. This way, you will have a `dimens.xml` inside `values-mdpi`, another one inside `values-hdpi`, and yet another in `values-xhdpi`.

I prefer another approach. I like to handle positioning of items using the screen dimensions. I get the screen width and height at runtime, and programmatically add margins and padding to layout items.

```
// Get screen dimensions

// Add a ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() to the view

    // Update height and width for items

    // Position items using screenWidth and screenHeight
```

This, kind of, fool-proofs the rendering. Not sure if this approach fails in some case.

**Edit:**

You can read through ['Providing Resources'](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) to know about the criteria that android uses to decide on the best possible resource for a given device/situation.

Comment: I believe it is the api level which is affecting the height of the button because I can get two different button heights by using the same exact code (which the markup above comes from) and just toggling the target sdk from 10 to 17. Note, this is on an emulator.

Comment: @Michael Yes, you are right about this. A button with width and height set to `wrap_content` did look different in size on two emulators running API 10 and API 17. But when I set the width and height to `100dp` and textsize to `20sp`, I got the following result: [Link](http://pho.to/3E9xJ). _Now_ they look the same. This hints at the default values being different between API versions. But, I could not confirm this.

Comment: any thoughts on where to find those default values?

Comment: @Michael A while back, I was looking for the value of `?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall`. I was using it to set the height of list item layout. This is where I found it: `[adt-bindle-windows-installation-directory] / sdk / platforms / android-[XX] / data / res / values / themes.xml`.

Comment: @Michael In `styles.xml`, you can find `<style name="Widget.Button">` which lists the default values. The default `textAppearance` is listed as `?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse`. You can find values for this using `<style name="TextAppearance.Small.Inverse">`: text-size listed is 14sp for both API-10 and API-17. But, I could not find the default values for width and height (which I think, would be defined in terms of padding).